# What is the correct way to ship a program built using MSYS2 and MingW to end users?

Tags: c, windows, deployment, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm building a C application on Windows using Msys2 and MingW.

This application will be shipped to Desktop Windows machines of end users who are not tech-savvy. I have two questions regarding this:

1. What is the best practice way to ship a Windows program built using Msys64 and MingW, to a different Windows machine which doesn't have these installed? Some sources on the internet and here on SO say we have no choice but to distribute the `exe` file in the same directory along with the MingW `dll`s it depends on. Or, to statically link the `exe` with the MingW `dll`s. But, I'd like to make sure if these are indeed the standard ways to do so. It seems odd that MingW wouldn't have a better way.
2. Suppose the said `exe` also at some point uses `LoadLibrary` API to dynamically load a `dll` (think plugin system). That `dll` was also built using `MingW` (and in this case of course will be shipped to end users along with the `exe`). Is there anything special I need to do to make sure that the `dll` will be loaded successfuly on a user machine without MingW installed?
3. In addition to 2: does the said DLL need an import library (`.lib`) present during compilation on the development machine, and/or during launch on the end machine?

EDIT: Please let me clarify, I am **not** using MSYS2 as a command line shell. I am working directly with the Mingw `gcc` through the Windows `cmd`, and have simply obtained Mingw from inside the MSYS2 download directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume this question is about MSYS2 and mingw-w64  , since there is no such thing as "msys64" .

MSYS2 offers three different **target** systems:

- Windows 32-bit
- Windows 64-bit
- MSYS2

each of which have entirely separate source trees for their development tools and packages under the MSYS2 installation.

This is not to be confused with different build systems -- the build system can be either Win32 or Win64.    For example if you chose Win64 as the build system and chose to install all three target systems then you will have have trees `msys64/mingw32`, `msys64/mingw64`, and `msys64/usr`

The MSYS2 installer creates startup scripts for each target that you installed.

---

If you target Win32 or Win64, then the compiled binaries (exe or dll) can be distributed as standalone products. You can do a static build with gcc or clang , producing a single standalone executable,  or you can do a build that depends on DLLs which you distribute with your executable.

It is standard for binary distributions to include all files that they require and are not provided by the target operating system,  this is not a peculiarity of mingw-w64.

The `LoadLibrary` search path is described [in the MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya?redirectedfrom=MSDN) .

If you target MSYS2 then the resulting binary SHOULD be run under a MSYS2 shell. This target offers some POSIX features that are not supported directly by mingw-w64. It can be considered a fork of Cygwin.  It would be possible to distribute a binary targeting MSYS2 along with a bunch of DLLs copied from the MSYS2 installation that you identify using dependency tracker.

Comment: can you specify dependency tracker?i mean how can i know which dlls are required?

Comment: @JatinParmar https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see any downside to this solution.
I am not much of a Windows user, but I must admit that the solution
of implicitly finding dynamic libraries where stands the executable
is of great help.
You put the whole content of your application (the executables and
the dynamic libraries/plugins) anywhere and as soon as you manage
to run the executable everything else will be found.

Of course, if you plan to deliver many different applications
with a common subset of dynamic libraries, it could be better
to put all theses libraries in a common place and adjust the
PATH environment variable accordingly.
But it is not worth the effort for a single application.

In a mingw-w64 (not exactly Msys64 and MingW, but very close)
based application (with plugins) that I delivered a few months ago,
I just provided libgcc_s_seh-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll and
libwinpthread-1.dll as a complement to my own binaries and it
worked without any problem.
Using  `objdump.exe -p my_program.exe` (then recursively
on the displayed result) helps finding the needed dynamic
libraries (like `ldd` on Linux or `otool -L` on Macosx).

That's what I like in the mingw-like solution: it makes a native
Windows application that does not depend on many other unusual
components (that the user would have had to retrieve first).

---

There is no need to deal with some `.lib` files; building a
`.dll` and linking against it is enough (see the example below).
It works exactly as we do on UNIX (with `.so` files).
I really don't know why Visual-C++ relies on a so complicated
combination of `.lib` and `.dll` files...

---

I just re-tested with this simple example.

file `prog.cpp`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

__declspec(dllimport)
int
my_library_function(int arg);

int
main()
{
  std::cout << "~~~~ entering " << __func__ << " ~~~~\n";
  int result=my_library_function(123);
  std::cout << "result=" << result << '\n';
  std::cout << "~~~~ still in " << __func__ << " ~~~~\n";
  HINSTANCE lib=LoadLibrary("my_plugin.dll");
  if(lib)
  {
    FARPROC symbol=GetProcAddress(lib, "my_plugin_function");
    if(symbol)
    {
      int (*fnct)(int)=NULL;
      memcpy(&fnct, &symbol, sizeof(fnct));
      int result=fnct(123);
      std::cout << "result=" << result << '\n';
    }
    FreeLibrary(lib);
  }
  std::cout << "~~~~ leaving " << __func__ << " ~~~~\n";
  return 0;
}
```

file `my_library.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

__declspec(dllexport)
int
my_library_function(int arg)
{
  std::cout << "~~~~ entering " << __func__ << " ~~~~\n";
  std::cout << "arg=" << arg << '\n';
  std::cout << "~~~~ leaving " << __func__ << " ~~~~\n";
  return 2*arg;
}
```

file `my_plugin.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int
my_plugin_function(int arg)
{
  std::cout << "~~~~ entering " << __func__ << " ~~~~\n";
  std::cout << "arg=" << arg << '\n';
  std::cout << "~~~~ leaving " << __func__ << " ~~~~\n";
  return 2*arg;
}
```

build process

```
==== compiling [opt=0] my_plugin.cpp ====
g++ -o my_plugin.o my_plugin.cpp -c   -g -O0  -MMD -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -Wfatal-errors -UNDEBUG  -std=c++17 -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-sign-conversion

==== linking [opt=0] my_plugin.dll ====
g++ -shared -o my_plugin.dll my_plugin.o   -g -O0

==== compiling [opt=0] my_library.cpp ====
g++ -o my_library.o my_library.cpp -c   -g -O0  -MMD -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -Wfatal-errors -UNDEBUG  -std=c++17 -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-sign-conversion

==== linking [opt=0] my_library.dll ====
g++ -shared -o my_library.dll my_library.o   -g -O0

==== compiling [opt=0] prog.cpp ====
g++ -o prog.o prog.cpp -c   -g -O0  -MMD -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -Wfatal-errors -UNDEBUG  -std=c++17 -Wno-missing-braces -Wno-sign-conversion

==== linking [opt=0] prog.exe ====
g++ -o prog.exe prog.o   -g -O0 -lmy_library
```

execution

```
C:\Work\PluginTest>prog.exe
~~~~ entering main ~~~~
~~~~ entering my_library_function ~~~~
arg=123
~~~~ leaving my_library_function ~~~~
result=246
~~~~ still in main ~~~~
~~~~ entering my_plugin_function ~~~~
arg=123
~~~~ leaving my_plugin_function ~~~~
result=246
~~~~ leaving main ~~~~

C:\Work\PluginTest>
```

This still works when the mingw64 directory (containing the toolchain)
is renamed, as soon as the files `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`,
`libstdc++-6.dll` and `libwinpthread-1.dll` are placed in the
same directory as `prog.exe`.
It even works when the `prog.exe` is launched by clicking (not
from the command line); to see this I had to add an infinite loop
at the end of the program to keep the window open long enough to
see the displayed messages.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. So in your experience, a DLL compiled using Mingw and dynamically loaded (aka `LoadLibrary`) should be able to run on a different non-Mingw machine, as long as the loading `exe` file has the MingW DLLs near it in the directory?

Comment: @AvivCohn as far as I remember, yes (with mingw-w64 at least). And I just untar mingw-w64 locally (the system is not aware of the installation, I can even rename or erase this installation directory) so the configuration for testing is the same as for a client without the tools installed. As soon as I reboot to Windows I will try again (it's been a long time) and I come back to you.

Comment: @AvivCohn I just checked (see the edit), and it works exactly as I remembered. Be aware that I used mingw-w64 and not exactly msys64+mingw (there may be some slight differences).

Comment: @AvivCohn an edit has been added to answer the third point you added afterwards to your question (about ``.lib`` files).

Comment: Hello, thanks again for your detailed input. Quick question: when I use Dependency Walker to find the dependencies of my `.exe` compiled using GCC from Mingw-w64, it shows no dependency on `libgcc*` - even though pretty much all programs compiled using GCC should depend on `libgcc*`.  Any idea why that is?